# What is Psalm 2:8 referring to?

Tags: psalms

Psalm 2:8

> Ask of Me, and I will surely give the nations as Your inheritance, and the very ends of the earth as your possession. (NASB)

Who is God speaking to here? And in what way will the nations be their inheritance? I understand that an evangelical-esque reading of this interprets the receiver as Jesus, but I’d like to hear other interpretations. If God is speaking to David, how will the nations be given as His inheritance? Is the only interpretation something that involved Jesus?

Answer (score 1):

The second Psalm is a well-know Messianic psalm as evidenced by the following references:

- V2 refers to the LORD's anointed one
- V7 refers to the LORD's Son
- V12 also refers to "the Son"

This is confirmed by the NT writers:

- V2 is quoted and applied to Jesus in Acts 4:25, 26
- V7 is quoted and applied to Jesus in Acts 13;33, Heb 1:5, 5:5
- V9 is quoted and applied to Jesus in Rev 2:27, 12:5, 19:15.

Thus we may readily conclude that V8 is referring to Jesus and Him being ruler of the nations.  There is another allusion to this same idea in Rev 11:15 -

> Then the seventh angel sounded his trumpet, and loud voices called out
> in heaven:
>
> “The kingdom of the world has become the kingdom of our Lord and of
> His Christ, and He will reign forever and ever.”

There appears to be another allusion to Ps 2:1 by Rev 11:18, again applying to Jesus.  Thus, Ps 2:7-9 is announcement by the LORD about the Son, Jesus, whose fulfillment is repeated in Rev 11;15.

Answer (score 1):

**What is Psalm 2:8 referring to?**

Psalm 2:7-8 refer to Jesus.

Psalm 2:7 NASB

> 7 “I will announce the decree of the Lord:  He said to Me, ‘You are My
> Son,  Today I have fathered You.

A prophesied in Psalm 2:7  God acknowledges at His baptism that Jesus is His Son:

Mark 1:10-11 NASB

> 10 And immediately coming up out of the water, He saw the heavens
> [a]opening, and the Spirit, like a dove, descending upon Him; 11 and a
> voice came from the heavens: “You are My beloved Son; in You I [b]am
> well pleased.”

According to the Psalm, God asks His Son. (Not David)

Psalm 2:8 NASB

> 8 Ask it of Me, and I will certainly give the nations as Your
> inheritance,And the ends of the earth as Your possession.

How will the nations be given as His inheritance?

Jesus has the inheritance as God’s Firstborn. Indeed, Jesus Christ “is the image of the invisible God, the firstborn of all creation.” (Colossians 1:15 NASB, KJV) All he has to do is ask and God "gives him nations as his inheritance and the ends of the earth as his possession."

Psalm 72:8 NASB

> 8 May he also rule from sea to sea,  And from the Euphrates River to
> the ends of the earth.

Hebrews 1:2 NASB

> 2 In these last days has spoken to us in His Son, whom He appointed
> heir of all things, through whom He also made the world.

Revelation 11:15 NASB

The Seventh Trumpet: Christ’s Reign Foreseen

> 15 Then the seventh angel sounded; and there were loud voices in
> heaven, saying, “The kingdom of the world has become the kingdom of
> our Lord and of His Christ; and He will reign forever and ever.”

Answer (score 0):

**Psalm 2:1** refers to [2 Samuel 5:17] :

> [1] "Why do nations assemble, and peoples plot vain things" (לָמָּה רָֽגְשׁ֣וּ גוֹיִ֑ם וּ֜לְאֻמִּ֗ים יֶהְגּוּ־רִֽיק)

- Refers to [2 Samuel 5:17] - "And the Philistines heard that they anointed David as king over Israel, and all the Philistines went up to seek David; and David heard and went down to the stronghold." (וַיִּשְׁמְע֣וּ פְלִשְׁתִּ֗ים כִּי־מָשְׁח֨וּ אֶת־דָּוִ֚ד לְמֶ֙לֶךְ֙ עַל־יִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל וַיַּעֲל֥וּ כָל־פְּלִשְׁתִּ֖ים לְבַקֵּ֣שׁ אֶת־דָּוִ֑ד וַיִּשְׁמַ֣ע דָּוִ֔ד וַיֵּ֖רֶד אֶל־הַמְּצוּדָֽה)

**Psalm 2:8** refers to [2 Samuel 5:19] :

> [8] "Ask of Me, and I will make nations your inheritance, and the ends of the earth your possession" (שְׁאַ֚ל מִמֶּ֗נִּי וְאֶתְּנָ֣ה ג֖וֹיִם נַֽחֲלָתֶ֑ךָ וַֽ֜אֲחֻזָּֽתְךָ֗ אַפְסֵי־אָֽרֶץ)

- Refers to [2 Samuel 5:19] - "And David inquired of YHVH saying: 'Shall I go up to the Philistines? will you deliver them into my hand?' And YHVH said unto David: 'Go up; for I will surely deliver the Philistines into your hand.' " (וַיִּשְׁאַ֨ל דָּוִ֚ד בַּֽיהֹוָה֙ לֵאמֹ֔ר הַאֶֽעֱלֶה֙ אֶל־פְּלִשְׁתִּ֔ים הֲתִתְּנֵ֖ם בְּיָדִ֑י וַיֹּ֨אמֶר יְהֹוָ֚ה אֶל־דָּוִד֙ עֲלֵ֔ה כִּֽי־נָתֹ֥ן אֶתֵּ֛ן אֶת־הַפְּלִשְׁתִּ֖ים בְּיָדֶֽךָ)

---

Who is God speaking to in Tehillim 2 verse 8?
**David (דָּוִד)**